# How to modify certain columns in a Matrix in Armadillo C++

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, armadillo

I have a very simple task in an Armadillo 10x10 matrix.
The task is to change the values of the columns `1,3,4` and `9` to `sqrt(2)`.

I already done the task
using (B is only ones)

```
B.cols(columns) *= sqrt(2);
```

I did this for every column and worked.

The problem here is that reading the documentation you can make this operation using

```
B.cols( vector of col indices )
```

and I want to learn how to use it but nothing seems to work

Comment: You could use `B.each_col()`, see [doc](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#each_colrow)

Comment: didnt work, the thing is that i dont know how the "VECTOR_OF_INDICES" should be introduced in the parameter

Answer (score 0):

Declare the "vector of col indices" as [uvec](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col) and put the column indices in it.

```
mat B(10, 11, fill::randu);

uvec column_indices = { 1, 3, 4, 9 };

B.cols(column_indices) *= sqrt(2);
```

(Just to be clear, C++ has zero-based indexing, so the first column has index 0, not 1).